# Can A VPN client have a domain name accessible worldwide associated to it

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, domain, vps

I have set up a VPS running Ubuntu, and on the VPS I have installed a virtual private network, using OpenVPN. the VPS server ip is : A.B.C.D
OpenVpn runs on port 1194. And have two clients connected to it, clientA, and ClientB. I would like to point a domain name sub.example.com to clientA is it possible? Also, I have tried to edit /etc/host file but it is not working. Is this feasable?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's nearly the same as assigning domain names to LAN computers (and the VPN server works much like a LAN router).

1. Make sure your OpenVPN server always assigns the same VPN IP address to this client. For example, you could enable `ifconfig-pool-persist /var/lib/openvpn/foo.pool` to make the server remember addresses automatically.
2. If the VPN assigns public addresses to clients, that's all, just put the address in DNS.
3. If the VPN assigns private addresses to clients, put the VPN *server's* public IP address in DNS – and you'll of course need to port-forward the necessary services from the VPN server's public IP address to the client's private address. You can use iptables DNAT rules on the server to implement port-forwarding.

   Alternatively, if you *only* need web (HTTP/HTTPS) for this client, you can run a reverse proxy (nginx, haproxy, Apache) on the server.

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed able to set up port forwarding to client A, so If I need the vpn to route incoming port 80 connections to either clientA or clientB depending on their hostname. My understanding is that incoming port 80 connection will be forwarded to the VPN private IP, and I would have to setup the hosts.conf file in a way that OpenVPN, knows to which client it has to forward the connection? Am I right?

Comment: That's actually beyond OpenVPN. At IP level, you cannot route/port-forward connections depending on just hostname -- if they're all made to the same IP address, then they are indistinguishable from each other. To achieve this with HTTP/HTTPS you will need to run a 'reverse proxy' on the VPN server, so that it will be able to extract the hostname from HTTP requests, or from TLS handshakes.

Comment: And, uh, I don't know what you mean by "hosts.conf". If you meant OpenVPN server config file -- sometimes yes, but in your case no. OpenVPN already knows all "main" IP addresses it has assigned to each client. Adding --iroute options to the OpenVPN server's config would be only needed if each client had a _dedicated_ public IP address, or more than one private IP address. Neither of which applies to what you're describing.

Comment: (To clarify: The reverse proxy doesn't strictly need to be on the VPN server itself; that's just the most natural place for it. Technically you _could_ keep forwarding port 80 to client A, and set up a reverse proxy on client A to handle domains B/C/D/E. But it would increase the load on client A, and it would also increase latency if A->B needs to go over the VPN again.)

Comment: Indeed I did set up a reverse proxy on client A and this did the trick for me :